# escapeshellarg without quotes to allow wildcards/globbing?

Tags: php, escaping, command-line-arguments, glob

I'd like to have something like `escapeshellarg` that allows wildcards/globbing, to do something like this:

```
$arg = escapeshellarg('fol der/*.ext');
echo `ls $arg -t | head -1`
```

but, of course quoting `ls`'s arguments disables globbing.

I guess there's some combination of `addslashes` and its cousins to get a well-escaped, non-quoted, argument (in this case: `fol\ der/*.ext`)?

I know about `glob()`, but I like `ls -t`...

Nice & short alternatives to `shell_exec("ls * -t | head -1")` welcome, if not what I'm asking for...

Comment: No. There isn't. the whole point of escaping shell args is to **PREVENT** shell metacharacters. There is no provision for "escape all metachars EXCEPT ..."

Comment: ah, okay, I thought the point was to escape spaces, to avoid something like `for i in *; do rm $i; done` in bash, which I step right into every time :) EDIT: of course! If you had filenames with, say, question marks, there'd be no way to discern their meta-ness...

Comment: Given your requirements, I think writing everything in PHP would be simpler.

Comment: @OwenBeresford - I guess so, but a PHP-only "sort by time" seems like such a p.i.t.a. :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$arg = escapeshellarg('fol der').'/*.ext';
```